# implement "android:textOff" & "android:textOn" property for toggle button programatically in Android

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android, android-button

I am trying to change the default On and Off text on the toggle button in Android. I am aware of how to do this in xml. My query is how to attain this programatically in code.

Could anyone please advise? Much thanks.

Comment: Any more advice, please, anyone??

Comment: The best way of attempting this is through:

ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton(this);

btn.setTextOn(string value);

btn.setTextOff(string value);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ToggleButton.setTextOn(String)` and `ToggleButton.setTextOff(String)`

Answer (score 1):

you can set in toggle button on/off in xml like below

// xml code for toggle button

```
 <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textOn="On"         //when your button on by clicking "On" text will be displayed
            android:textOff="Off" />   //When you off the toggle button "Off" text will be displayed
```

in java code.

```
    ToggleButton toggleButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggBtn);

toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(toggleButton.getText().toString().equals("on")){
                ////do when toggle button is on 
                }else if(toggleButton.getText().toString().equals("off")){
                // do when toggle button is off 
                }   

            }
        });
```

Comment: llango could you please clarify some more, preferably with some code? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton(this); //this is optional and you should use your way to create the button :)
    if (btn.isChecked())
    {
        btn.setText("something");
    }
    else
    {
        btn.setText("something else");
    }
```

Advice: you should place this validation in an onclickListener :)

Comment: Thanks Arkde, however this does not seem to work..the values remain the same